# Error occurred during SQL query execution Reason: SQL Error [1061] [42000]: Duplicate key name 'book_lending'

Tags: mysql, database, dbeaver

i'm getting duplicate key error for the below code. This table consists of 3 foreign keys , and 2 normal columns, a total of 5 columns.

````
create table book_lending(
book_id int , 
foreign key book_lending(book_id) references book(book_id) on delete cascade,
foreign key book_lending(branch_id) references library_prog(branch)  on delete cascade, 
branch_id int ,
foreign key book_lending(card_no) references cards(card_no) on delete cascade, 
card_no int ,
date_out date ,

due_date date,

primary key(book_id, branch_id , card_no )

);```
````

Answer (score 1):

You get a duplicate key error, because you tried to create the foreign key constraint named `book_lending` three times. Rename the keys, e. g.

```
create table book_lending(
  book_id int, 
  branch_id int,
  card_no int,
  date_out date,
  due_date date,
  primary key(book_id, branch_id , card_no),
  foreign key book_lending_book(book_id) references book(book_id) on delete cascade,
  foreign key book_lending_prog(branch_id) references library_prog(branch)  on delete cascade, 
  foreign key book_lending_cards(card_no) references cards(card_no) on delete cascade
);
```